# Azure App Service not installing all node dependencies

Tags: node.js, azure, npm-install, azure-web-app-service

I have a nodejs azure app service. It seems like npm isn't installing all the dependencies correctly. The site runs locally fine, when i try in azure, I get 500 responses. 
When I check the log, it shows various node dependencies missing. After I install the missing one using the console on the portal, another missing dependency notification pops up.
Using git deploy, I've tried just committing the entire node_modules folder, but for some reason, all the bits don't get uploaded.
Grateful for any ideas about how to sort this out.

Comment: I used FTP deploy to get the node_modules I was working with in dev, deployed. Would still like to solve the mystery though

Comment: Exact same problem. It's due to the horribly slow storage I think. NPM/Yarn will think the install is done but it isnt.